# How to do create a thumbnail of many sites?

Tags: python, perl, parser

I've got a list of 2500 websites and need to grab a little screenshot of them - to create a thumbnail

How do I do that?  Well I could try to parse the sites.

Either with Perl or Python

Answer (score 1):

If you just need a screenshot / thumbnail, then it is probably best to use one of the many existing thumbnail generator services around.

[This site](http://www.shrinktheweb.com) for example allows 5000 free screenshots a month (with a daily limit of several hundred) and has an API, so if you have a list of URLs in a file, you could create a script that did something like:

```
 wget http://www.shrinktheweb.com/api?site=http://thesite.com
```

The above is just made up, you'll have to read their api docs to work out how best to access the api, but just repeat the command for each site.

wget can be obtain [here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm) for windows, and if you are using linux it will probably be installed already, but otherwise it will be available in the repositories, so use the package manager to install.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Paul's advice, but if you really want to do it on your own, then I would look at the Perl module [Image::Magick::Thumbnail](https://metacpan.org/module/Image::Magick::Thumbnail), which has a fairly simple interface - you just load up the image using the `Image::Magick` module, then pass the resulting object to `Image::Magick::Thumbnail::create` and write the resulting object back out to disk.